# Zariski closure of a group generated by Jordan cell

Tags: algebraic-groups

Suppose we have a subgroup $G \subset \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$ generated by a Jordan cell. What is the closure of $G$ in Zariski topology?

(That seems for me a rather natural question for which I know the answer only in the case $n=2$ and a unipotent cell - so I wonder why nobody has answered something)